# list() is not updating in the for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, mle

I want to estimate the parameters of the skew normal distribution using `mle2` function in `r`. I have copied my `r` function below.

```
library(bbmle)
library(sn)
y = c(rsn(n=50, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=1, tau=0, dp=NULL), rsn(n=50, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=6, tau=0, dp=NULL))
n= length(y)

sn.fit = function(xi, omega, alpha){
  -sum(dsn(y, xi=0, omega=1, alpha, log = TRUE))
}

parl = list()
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  dat = list(y[1:i])
parl[[i]]= mle2(sn.fit, start = list(xi = 0, omega = 1, alpha = 1), data = dat)@coef

}
parll = do.call("rbind", parl)
parll
```

The output is given below.

```
> parll
       xi omega    alpha
  [1,]  0     1 1.408533
  [2,]  0     1 1.408533
  [3,]  0     1 1.408533
  [4,]  0     1 1.408533
  [5,]  0     1 1.408533
  [6,]  0     1 1.408533
  [7,]  0     1 1.408533
  [8,]  0     1 1.408533
  [9,]  0     1 1.408533
 [10,]  0     1 1.408533
 [11,]  0     1 1.408533
 [12,]  0     1 1.408533
```

Since my intention is to estimate `alpha` for `y[1:i]` for `i=1,...,(n-1)`. Why my result is not updating into the list?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've hard coded `y` into the `sn.fit` function. Thus you are using the same data for every call, it's not changing. The `data=` part only works if you pass a formula, not a function to `mle2`.

Comment: @MrFlick, Am I able to improve this? Thanks.

Comment: @MrFlick is this correct? right? `parl = list()
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  dat = y[1:i]
  sn.fit = function(xi, omega, alpha){
    -sum(dsn(dat, xi=0, omega=1, alpha, log = TRUE))
  }
parl[[i]]= mle2(sn.fit, start = list(xi = 0, omega = 1, alpha = 1), data = list(dat))@coef

}
parll = do.call("rbind", parl)
parll`